# Bash script to copy folders

Tags: bash

I would need to copy multiple source folders to target location. The script should create required destination folders.

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: We need a bit more information I'm afraid. Are the multiple directories located inside one single directory. Is the target location local or remote? Should the directories be copied with their contents, recursively, or just the top-level, or just the directory structure? Is the issue that you know how to do this for _one_ directory, but not many?

Comment: what have you tried? what happened when you tried it?  how did that differ from what you expected to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit sparse in your description of what you need, hence the comments to your question. However, based on your limited input:

You do not need a script to achieve what you request. Just use cli-commands. Like this:

```
mkdir destination;cp -r source1 source2 sourceX destination
```

This may or may not not suit your needs. If the latter, you need to specify your request.  There are lots of variants to these commands which could be what you are after.

If you need to have these commands in a script, just put them in a file and have your shell of choice execute them.

Comment: I'd recommend you don't use `<` and `>` to delimit placeholders as these are a common part of shell syntax

Comment: Good point. Changed.